# API not accepting data from Form in express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have an api as follows, the problem I am having is that when I create aa form using handlebars and submit the form to this API, I know it is hitting the api because it show the validation message but it is not accepting the values provided in the form:

```
exports.register = function (req, res, next) {
  var username = _.get(req.body, 'username');
  var password = _.get(req.body, 'password');

  if (!username) {
    throw {username: 'This field is required.', status: 400};
  }
  if (!password) {
    throw {password: 'This field is required.', status: 400};
  }

  Users.register(dbUtils.getSession(req), username, password)
    .then(response => writeResponse(res, response, 201))
    .catch(next);
};
```

So basically is a simple registration api, the form ask for user name and password and then you click submit.

Following is the code for my handlebars file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body">

            <h3 class="text-center">Account Register</h3>
            <form action="/api/v0/register" method="POST" enctype='application/json'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{name}}" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{password}}" required>
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click submit the page show the response from my route that username is required. What I am confused about is why the username and password is not being detected by the route:

Message:

```
{
"username": "This field is required."
}
```

I am using Nodejs, express, express handlebars.

My Complete app.js is as follows:

```
var express = require('express')
  , path = require('path')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , nconf = require('./config')
  , swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc')
  , methodOverride = require('method-override')
  , errorHandler = require('errorhandler')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  , setAuthUser = require('./middlewares/setAuthUser')
  , neo4jSessionCleanup = require('./middlewares/neo4jSessionCleanup')
  , writeError = require('./helpers/response').writeError;

  const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');


var app = express()
  , api = express();

app.use(nconf.get('api_path'), api);

// Handlebars middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var swaggerDefinition = {
  info: {
    title: 'Neo4j Movie Demo API (Node/Express)',
    version: '1.0.0',
    description: '',
  },
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  basePath: '/',
};

// options for the swagger docs
var options = {
  // import swaggerDefinitions
  swaggerDefinition: swaggerDefinition,
  // path to the API docs
  apis: ['./routes/*.js'],
};

// initialize swagger-jsdoc
var swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

// serve swagger
api.get('/swagger.json', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(swaggerSpec);
});

app.use('/docs', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'swaggerui')));
app.set('port', nconf.get('PORT'));

//api.use(bodyParser.json());
api.use(methodOverride());

//enable CORS
api.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});

//api custom middlewares:
api.use(setAuthUser);
api.use(neo4jSessionCleanup);


// User Register Route
app.get('/users/register', (req, res) => {

  res.render('users/register');
});

//api routes
api.post('/register', routes.users.register);
api.post('/login', routes.users.login);
api.get('/users/me', routes.users.me);
api.get('/movies', routes.movies.list);
api.get('/movies/recommended', routes.movies.getRecommendedMovies);
api.get('/movies/rated', routes.movies.findMoviesRatedByMe);
api.get('/movies/:id',  routes.movies.findById);
api.get('/movies/genre/:id',  routes.movies.findByGenre);
api.get('/movies/daterange/:start/:end', routes.movies.findMoviesByDateRange);
api.get('/movies/directed_by/:id', routes.movies.findMoviesByDirector);
api.get('/movies/acted_in_by/:id', routes.movies.findMoviesByActor);
api.get('/movies/written_by/:id', routes.movies.findMoviesByWriter);
api.post('/movies/:id/rate', routes.movies.rateMovie);
api.delete('/movies/:id/rate', routes.movies.deleteMovieRating);
api.get('/people', routes.people.list);
api.get('/people/:id', routes.people.findById);
api.get('/people/bacon', routes.people.getBaconPeople);
api.get('/genres', routes.genres.list);

//api error handler
api.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if(err && err.status) {
    writeError(res, err);
  }
  else next(err);
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port') + ' see docs at /docs');
});
```

This is user the user route file:

```
var Users = require('../models/users')
  , writeResponse = require('../helpers/response').writeResponse
  , writeError = require('../helpers/response').writeError
  , loginRequired = require('../middlewares/loginRequired')
  , dbUtils = require('../neo4j/dbUtils')
  , _ = require('lodash');


exports.register = function (req, res, next) {


  var username = _.get(req.body, 'username');
  var password = _.get(req.body, 'password');

  if (!username) {
    throw {username: 'This field is required.', status: 400};
  }
  if (!password) {
    throw {password: 'This field is required.', status: 400};
  }

  Users.register(dbUtils.getSession(req), username, password)
    .then(response => writeResponse(res, response, 201))
    .catch(next);
};


exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
  var username = _.get(req.body, 'username');
  var password = _.get(req.body, 'password');

  if (!username) {
    throw {username: 'This field is required.', status: 400};
  }
  if (!password) {
    throw {password: 'This field is required.', status: 400};
  }

  Users.login(dbUtils.getSession(req), username, password)
    .then(response => writeResponse(res, response))
    .catch(next);
};


exports.me = function (req, res, next) {
  loginRequired(req, res, () => {
    var authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    var match = authHeader.match(/^Token (\S+)/);
    if (!match || !match[1]) {
      throw {message: 'invalid authorization format. Follow `Token <token>`', status: 401};
    }

    var token = match[1];
    Users.me(dbUtils.getSession(req), token)
      .then(response => writeResponse(res, response))
      .catch(next);
  })
};
```

This is my user model file:

```
"use strict"

var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var randomstring = require("randomstring");
var _ = require('lodash');
var dbUtils = require('../neo4j/dbUtils');
var User = require('../models/neo4j/user');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var register = function (session, username, password) {
  return session.run('MATCH (user:User {username: {username}}) RETURN user', {username: username})
    .then(results => {
      if (!_.isEmpty(results.records)) {
        throw {username: 'username already in use', status: 400}
      }
      else {
        return session.run('CREATE (user:User {id: {id}, username: {username}, password: {password}, api_key: {api_key}}) RETURN user',
          {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            username: username,
            password: hashPassword(username, password),
            api_key: randomstring.generate({
              length: 20,
              charset: 'hex'
            })
          }
        ).then(results => {
            return new User(results.records[0].get('user'));
          }
        )
      }
    });
};

var me = function (session, apiKey) {
  return session.run('MATCH (user:User {api_key: {api_key}}) RETURN user', {api_key: apiKey})
    .then(results => {
      if (_.isEmpty(results.records)) {
        throw {message: 'invalid authorization key', status: 401};
      }
      return new User(results.records[0].get('user'));
    });
};

var login = function (session, username, password) {
  return session.run('MATCH (user:User {username: {username}}) RETURN user', {username: username})
    .then(results => {
        if (_.isEmpty(results.records)) {
          throw {username: 'username does not exist', status: 400}
        }
        else {
          var dbUser = _.get(results.records[0].get('user'), 'properties');
          if (dbUser.password != hashPassword(username, password)) {
            throw {password: 'wrong password', status: 400}
          }
          return {token: _.get(dbUser, 'api_key')};
        }
      }
    );
};

function hashPassword(username, password) {
  var s = username + ':' + password;
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(s).digest('hex');
}

module.exports = {
  register: register,
  me: me,
  login: login
};
```

I have also tried to console.log req.body.username and it is undefined for some reason.

Comment: You'll have to show more of your express code.  Also, why are you using `_.get()` to access a simple property?  Do you have form processing middleware installed?  How is the exported function being called?

Comment: I was actually using a sample project from neo4j graph database. I am calling the register api in the form
<form action="/api/v0/register" method="POST">

I don't have a middleware as such I think.

Comment: Well, you need middleware in order to parse form submissions into the `req.body`  object.  That doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: Can you suggest an example.

Comment: Now that you've shown your express code, you already have the `body-parser` middleware installed.  I don't know why your form submission doesn't work.

Comment: yes...exactly...I have been hitting a wall with this...Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What does `console.log(req.body)` in the `.post()` handler show?

Comment: is it possible that my form has issues with it. I have tested my api with postman and it works fine. I use application/json as content-type and write the username and password in the body then send it, my user gets created successfully. 
But when I use the form as shown above I get no data in the username and password fields.

Comment: Not clear where in code do you mean, can you specify I can check immediately

Comment: Did you try removing `enctype='application/json'` from your form tag?   Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), that is not a legal value for that attribute and may be messing you up.  Just let the browser use the normal default value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and your middleware will parse it just fine.

Comment: I mean in the code that is trying to access your form data in `req.body`.

Comment: For the form, I have tried with removing the enctype completely and nothing happens. 
And it show nothing when I console.log in the route register method.

Comment: it says undefined in the exports.register when I console log the req.body

Comment: For some reason when I send the post request using postman it works fine, but in the application it fails. the only difference is that I am using a handlebars form to access the api.

Comment: You can look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger to see EXACTLY what the browser is sending to your server and see if that's what you expect.

Comment: interestingly, my body-parser is giving me nothing even in app.js, for some reson when i type req.body. it shows me none of the fields from the form.

Comment: why do you have two separate app objects?  One called `app` and one called `api`?  Perhaps `api` should be `const api = express.Router()`?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware:

```
// Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

needs to be BEFORE you insert the `api` router into the routing chain.  As you have it now, requests are routed to your `api` router without this middleware executing.

So, it should be like this:

```
// Body Parser middleware
// must come before any requests, middleware or routers that want to use
// the body-parser middleware results
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(nconf.get('api_path'), api);
```

---

Also, change this:

```
, api = express();
```

to:

```
, api = express.Router();
```

so you're just using a router instead of an app object.  The app object is also a router, but a plain router is really what you want here.

Comment: @AminBaig - DB code issues would be a new issue.  If you can't figure that one out, I'd suggest a new question that focuses on the details of that. I don't know your db so I can't really help with that.